# Java Package Organization

Tags: java, package, project-organization

I have been struggling for days but I could find a good way to organize packages.I have created some classes and I want to have them in every project like all the java classes but i can't. for example if i create a class and define the package like this

```
package myclass.importatnt.test;
```

this class is available only in this project. If I want to have this class in other projects I have to copy/paste the folder **myclass**  in the other project folder and this is really boring. Is there any way to organize the packages so I can use them in any moment?

Comment: Sounds like you've gotten to the point where you need to investigate using a build tool such as maven (http://maven.apache.org/) - these tools allow separate projects to reference one-another, in the manner you describe. Tread with caution! It's a long dark path fraught with peril, but you'll be in a much better place once you master one or more of these build tools.

Comment: Yep, maven & ant & such are great!

Comment: I'll just augment what @Ron said by looking at Maven Multi Module projects.

Comment: I'll add that you want to exploit the IDE you're using (Eclipse, etc.) to support multiple inter-dependent projects.  It's true that maven is the ultimate answer, but you want to understand how your IDE solves the local problem first before stepping up to maven.

Comment: Totally agree. The Maven Eclipse support is incredible (my favorite is the auto source code download). Its well worth the annoyance of the verbose XML that is Maven.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some utility classes that you want to reuse in multiple projects.

Instead of copying the source code of the classes in every project, you should instead compile the classes, package the class files in a jar file, and add this jar file in the classpath of every project needing them.

That's what you do with every other librery that you use (commons-lang, guava, whatever...), and there's no reason not to do the same with your own utility classes.

Answer (score 0):

If your using eclipse, go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path, and add your project to the list of required projects (under the Projects tab). Then you should be able to import them.